# How to push MySQL Database Data to a MVC .NET web application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, push-notification

I would like to know how I can push data changes in a MySQL database table to an MVC Web Application. So if the table changes - the web app gets updated .. I am not talking polling or querying - I am talking MySQL has a table changed - and that table data change gets sent to the Web App - clients.

I see that SQL server seems to have some functionality built in (full version but not in express), I am not seeing this in MySQL database either (which is really what I need).

Comment: You should be able to get inspiration from this [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) simple example of "chat".

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292906/sqldependency-on-a-mariadb-mysql-database/51293221

Comment: In MySQL you basically have to resort to polling; see my reply to a feature request for a SqlDependency equivalent here: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/522#issuecomment-399457142

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use `SqlDependency` and `SignalR` for your requirement.

But `SqlDependency` not available for MySql database.

This is a sample in SQL Server + SignalR https://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency